# Can Autocomplete component have different value and option types?

Tags: autocomplete, material-ui

As per docs, [Autocomplete](https://material-ui.com/api/autocomplete/#props) component has no distinction between option and actual value.

I have a list of options as objects with ids. When I select an option I want to get its id as a value, not the object itself. Also, when I set the value of Autocomplete I want to pass in id only.

Is it possible?

```js
<Autocomplete
  options={[{id: 1, label: 'foo'}, {id: 2, label: 'bar'}]}
  value={1}
  onChange={(_, value) => { /* value should be number (id) */ }}
/>
```

**Update:** option label should remain configurable

Answer (score 1):

Ciao, unfortunately value on `onChange` event returns one of the `options` selected. So is not possible to return only one attribute of the element.

The only thing you can do is take the `value.id`:

```
<Autocomplete
   options={[
      { id: 1, label: "foo" },
      { id: 2, label: "bar" }
   ]}
   getOptionLabel={(option) => option.label}    // this to show label on Autocomplete
   getOptionSelected={(option, value) => option.id === value.id}   // this to compare option on id value
   onChange={(event, value) => console.log(value.id)}  // here access to id property of value object
   ...
/>
```

[Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-8uc7k?file=/demo.js) a codesandbox example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, in this case, one will see id as an option label, not an actual label property. I clarified my question

Comment: @amankkg I upadated my answer (and codesandbox). But I think you already know what I wrote :)